# Ubuntu 20.04 got stuck at boot after update!

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04

Here is the image Ubuntu Boot screen stuck at booting:

[image: 1]
Anyone can tell me what is really happening here! Ubuntu Boot has been stuck here from 1 hour! I updated Ubuntu 18 to 20.04 and after updating Ubuntu got stuck at boot you can see on Image! Nothing happening here. What should I do!

EDIT - This is the first time boot after update!